# Using pattern/matcher to extract a substring

Tags: java, regex

I want to get a substring starting with `TKK_` using regex and `matcher` in java. The string is actually a URL such as

```
http://somewhere.com/core?item=TKK_43123
```

So far, I wrote this based on this [example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html#multiple-groups)

```
String pattern = "TKK_.+?";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern );
Matcher m = r.matcher(url);
```

But printing `m.group(1)` says `No match found`. I want to get `TKK_43123`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
String pattern = "TKK_\\d+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher("http://somewhere.com/core?item=TKK_43123");
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); 
} 
// => TKK_43123
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/4SBE4R)

The `\d+` will match 1 or more digits after `TKK_`.

Note that using a lazily quantified pattern at the end of the string is almost never what you want because it matches the *minimal* number of chars to return a valid match. So, `.+?` at the end of the pattern will always match just 1 char. `.*?` at the end of the pattern will match an empty string.

And surely always remember to actually *run* the *Matcher* using `.find()` or `.matches()`, otherwise, you won't be able to access any groups since no match has been found yet.

Comment: If there are letters and/or digits after `TKK_`, replace `\\d+` with `\\w+`.

Comment: Thanks. A side question... If I remove the `m.find()`, the println says no match found. Is that OK?

Comment: @mahmood: *And surely always remember to actually run the Matcher using `.find()` or `.matches()`, otherwise, you won't be able to access any groups since no match has been found yet.* - DON'T remove that.